# New Media Image attribute not showing up in product variable

Tags: php, magento

I've created an new image attribute, its purpose is to serve as a rollover option. I've implemented my version of it but I've realised on the catalog/product/list.phtml the others attribute come up in the data but not the newly created one. Why doesn't it show the new attribute in the data? Is that normal?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Please reindex after create and assign attribute to attribute
   set.
2. $product =
   Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); and
       after you can get your attribute.

Comment: I have reindexed, the thing is we shouldn't even have to get the Model. The $_item variable should have the newly created attribute.